# whats the differance between G.729 codec variations

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, codec, g729

what is the difference between 
G.729
G.729A
G.729AB

and if I have codecs set up for G729 in asterisk does this mean that G729A and G.729AB will work?

thanks

Comment: What have you read on it? What do the docs say, where have you found the docs?

Comment: docs say that G.729a is "Lower Complexity G.729" but it doesn’t mention compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**G.729a** is a compatible extension of G.729 that needs less CPU because it has lower speech quality. It is compatible with G729.

Some of its features are:

- Sampling frequency 8 kHz/16-bit (80 samples for 10 ms frames)
- Fixed bit rate (8 kbit/s 10 ms frames)
- Fixed frame size (10 bytes for 10 ms frame)
- Algorithmic delay is 15 ms per frame, with 5 ms look-ahead delay

**G.729b:**

- Not compatible with G.729 or G.729a
- Has a silence compression method that enables the voice activity detection module (VAD). It is used to detect voice activity in the signal.
- It includes a discontinuous transmission (DTX) module which decides on updating the background noise parameters for non speech (noisy frames).
- Uses 2-byte Silence Insertion Descriptor (SID) frames transmitted to initiate comfort noise generation (CNG). If transmission is stopped, and the link goes quiet because of no speech, the receiving side might assume that the link has been cut. By inserting comfort noise, analog hiss is simulated digitally during silence to assure the receiver that the link is active and operational.

Read more at its [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.729)

Answer (score 2):

Asterisk support g729a only. So you have no other options.

G729b is not compatible with g729a, g729ab mean both variant supported by switch.